# How can I customize the Unity Launcher?

Tags: customization

The Arc Theme has a screenshot that has a really nice launcher, nice icons for the launcher *only* ([here](http://darkdawg.deviantart.com/art/White-Pixel-Icons-252310560)), an options panel on the top, and a really cool Scopes icon down on the bottom.

How can I do this?
[image: Awesome Desktop]

P.S. I already have Unity Tweak Tool installed, along with the theme applied.

**EDIT: This is what I'm talking about**
[image: What I want]

**This is what I have. I only want to change the icons for the launcher, but keep Numix everywhere else.**

[image: What I have]

Thanks!

Comment: The top panel in the Arc theme image you pasted suggests it's Gnome environment, not Unity. The giveaway is the clock in the middle of the panel and the characteristic icons in the top right.  They probably used a plugin/extension to lock Gnome's favorites bar to be always shown, and applied  theme to the environment

Comment: See this image : http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-v4epkdsJSNg/UIWPZIUIrbI/AAAAAAAALN4/ntdIvuG9IE4/s1600/gnome3.png  The default gnome favorites bar has the same characteristic icon at the bottom, only not stretched - that's a job for a plugin

Comment: I would make desktop files and change the Icons of them... Then I would change the Unity Icons files. Ask if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install Unity Tweak Tool and then add the relevant PPAs for the themes and icons you want.

Comment: Thank you but I already have the Unity Tweak Tool. I just wanted to know about the Launcher. How can I customize the icons only on the launcher? What is the app that allows him to move Scopes down?